# How to do multiple subscription in stripe version 5.3.0.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe 5.3.0 with ASP .NET. I'm trying to create multiple subscriptions for one customer within a single invoice. I tested it within the stripe and it works correctly. You can check it with [this link](https://invoice.stripe.com/i/acct_1Ou9FwCKifPDqZIA/test_YWNjdF8xT3U5RndDS2lmUERxWklBLF9QbDVvZVAzNXJ4VlY0blVOREM1eHNTN2V5UDZXeWZQLDEwMTQ1ODU1MA020030XnkGvj?s=db). I can create a single subscription with the code mentioned below.

```
var subscriptionService = new StripeSubscriptionService(stApiKey);
StripeSubscription stripeSubscription = subscriptionService.Create(cusid, "1000");
```

This code works fine and creates a subscription on Stripe. How can I pass two or multiple planId to the below code? Is there any other way to create a subscription with multiple planId?

```
StripeSubscription stripeSubscription = subscriptionService.Create(string customerId, string planId);
```

In Visual Studio, they suggest a code like this.

```
StripeSubscription StripeSubscriptionService.Create(string customerId, string planId,[StripeSubscriptionCreateOptions createOptions = null],[StripeRequestOptions requestOptions = null])
```

Do you guys have any documents related to stripe version 5.3.0 or Please Help me solve this problem?

Comment: stripe-dotnet v5.3.0 is a very old version and doesn't support creating subscription with multiple items. The latest stripe-dotnet is [v43.19.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/releases/tag/v43.19.0). I'd recommend upgrading to the latest stripe-dotnet version and follow the integration guide [here](https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements&lang=dotnet).

Comment: This is an old project. I don't have permission to upgrade. That's why I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of would be to create the Subscription with one item, then add items sequentially using this API call https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscription_items/create?lang=dotnet. You could set the Susbcription on trial while you do this, then end the trial once you have all your subscription items added. Naturally, this would be pretty awkward even if it works.